# Microsoft Office Communicator 2007: Importing Contact Group from XML file

Tags: xml, windows, import, ms-office, office-communicator

*Microsoft Office Communicator 2007: Importing Contact Group from XML file*
**OS:** Windows XP SP3
**Office:** 2007
**Application:** Communicator
**Details:**
I am trying import a group of contacts to microsoft office communicator 2007.
Specifically I would like to import a group from this XML list.
**Currently attempted:**
At the moment I have got as far as retrieving a list of contacts via an XML file from:

> C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Communicator

However I cannot find anywhere on communicator to import it.
Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching I found the answer myself, which is to use something called the LCSAddContacts.WSF tool.

Guide can be found at:

wxe.winxnet.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=14 – user1228891 41 secs ago edit